# Rails ckeditor uploads image only locally, not in docker

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, docker, ckeditor

I'm using rails 5.0.1 with the gem 'ckeditor', github: 'galetahub/ckeditor'.

Running locally when I upload an image it works:

```
Started POST "/ckeditor/pictures?CKEditor=blog_content&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=en" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-08-25 13:42:46 +0200
Processing by Ckeditor::PicturesController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"upload"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fdbb2751418 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/var/folders/ct/h7f4s97j5g5_8kt74w7z9j7w0000gn/T/RackMultipart20170825-15213-h6z3o4.jpg>, @original_filename="Celina.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"upload\"; filename=\"Celina.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "ckCsrfToken"=>"KWW95qRoTkkliU37ytqWhxGEg0Qmlo2BlMa3jhY0", "CKEditor"=>"blog_content", "CKEditorFuncNum"=>"1", "langCode"=>"en"}
Command :: PATH=/usr/bin/:$PATH; identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/ct/h7f4s97j5g5_8kt74w7z9j7w0000gn/T/9a373c13873aa5b41008cdf6948f3c9a20170825-15213-10eo1d0.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
Command :: PATH=/usr/bin/:$PATH; identify -format %m '/var/folders/ct/h7f4s97j5g5_8kt74w7z9j7w0000gn/T/9a373c13873aa5b41008cdf6948f3c9a20170825-15213-10eo1d0.jpg[0]'
Command :: PATH=/usr/bin/:$PATH; convert '/var/folders/ct/h7f4s97j5g5_8kt74w7z9j7w0000gn/T/9a373c13873aa5b41008cdf6948f3c9a20170825-15213-10eo1d0.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "800>" '/var/folders/ct/h7f4s97j5g5_8kt74w7z9j7w0000gn/T/81df6ad10e023d4b1d778924afca264320170825-15213-191pjjb'
Command :: PATH=/usr/bin/:$PATH; identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/ct/h7f4s97j5g5_8kt74w7z9j7w0000gn/T/9a373c13873aa5b41008cdf6948f3c9a20170825-15213-10eo1d0.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
Command :: PATH=/usr/bin/:$PATH; identify -format %m '/var/folders/ct/h7f4s97j5g5_8kt74w7z9j7w0000gn/T/9a373c13873aa5b41008cdf6948f3c9a20170825-15213-10eo1d0.jpg[0]'
Command :: PATH=/usr/bin/:$PATH; convert '/var/folders/ct/h7f4s97j5g5_8kt74w7z9j7w0000gn/T/9a373c13873aa5b41008cdf6948f3c9a20170825-15213-10eo1d0.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "x100" -crop "118x100+8+0" +repage '/var/folders/ct/h7f4s97j5g5_8kt74w7z9j7w0000gn/T/81df6ad10e023d4b1d778924afca264320170825-15213-4zjjfu'
   (0.4ms)  BEGIN
Command :: PATH=/usr/bin/:$PATH; identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/var/folders/ct/h7f4s97j5g5_8kt74w7z9j7w0000gn/T/9a373c13873aa5b41008cdf6948f3c9a20170825-15213-10eo1d0.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
  SQL (1.0ms)  INSERT INTO "ckeditor_assets" ("data_file_name", "data_content_type", "data_file_size", "data_fingerprint", "type", "width", "height", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9) RETURNING "id"  [["data_file_name", "Celina.jpg"], ["data_content_type", "image/jpeg"], ["data_file_size", 20803], ["data_fingerprint", "64cabe13eace3919caf99ca7fc5ce98a"], ["type", "Ckeditor::Picture"], ["width", 300], ["height", 223], ["created_at", "2017-08-25 11:42:46.485116"], ["updated_at", "2017-08-25 11:42:46.485116"]]
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
  Rendering html template
  Rendered html template (0.0ms)
Completed 200 OK in 212ms (Views: 2.4ms | ActiveRecord: 5.6ms)
```

But when I run the project in docker without changing anything it gives me the error message: **Data content type is invalid**.

```
web_1  | Started POST "/ckeditor/pictures?CKEditor=blog_content&CKEditorFuncNum=1&langCode=en" for xxx.xx.x.x at 2017-08-25 12:43:29 +0000
web_1  | Processing by Ckeditor::PicturesController#create as HTML
web_1  |   Parameters: {"upload"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x000033deb977a8 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20170825-1-26b8ip.jpg>, @original_filename="Celina.jpg", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"upload\"; filename=\"Celina.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, "ckCsrfToken"=>"KWW95qRoTkkliU37ytqWhxGEg0Qmlo2BlMa3jhY0", "CKEditor"=>"blog_content", "CKEditorFuncNum"=>"1", "langCode"=>"en"}
web_1  | Command :: PATH=/usr/bin/:$PATH; identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/9a373c13873aa5b41008cdf6948f3c9a20170825-1-d4ds2v.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
web_1  | Command :: PATH=/usr/bin/:$PATH; identify -format %m '/tmp/9a373c13873aa5b41008cdf6948f3c9a20170825-1-d4ds2v.jpg[0]'
web_1  | Command :: PATH=/usr/bin/:$PATH; convert '/tmp/9a373c13873aa5b41008cdf6948f3c9a20170825-1-d4ds2v.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "800>" '/tmp/fdc33e93e3e5f5ae6778f9e43bf8b70620170825-1-wddlyh'
web_1  | Command :: PATH=/usr/bin/:$PATH; identify -format '%wx%h,%[exif:orientation]' '/tmp/9a373c13873aa5b41008cdf6948f3c9a20170825-1-d4ds2v.jpg[0]' 2>/dev/null
web_1  | Command :: PATH=/usr/bin/:$PATH; identify -format %m '/tmp/9a373c13873aa5b41008cdf6948f3c9a20170825-1-d4ds2v.jpg[0]'
web_1  | Command :: PATH=/usr/bin/:$PATH; convert '/tmp/9a373c13873aa5b41008cdf6948f3c9a20170825-1-d4ds2v.jpg[0]' -auto-orient -resize "x100" -crop "118x100+8+0" +repage '/tmp/fdc33e93e3e5f5ae6778f9e43bf8b70620170825-1-sf9kaf'
web_1  |    (0.2ms)  BEGIN
web_1  |    (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
web_1  |   Rendering html template
web_1  |   Rendered html template (0.0ms)
web_1  | Completed 200 OK in 259ms (Views: 8.9ms | ActiveRecord: 28.6ms)
```

Any ideas? Thanks

[EDIT]

Dockerfile

FROM ruby:2.3.3-alpine

```
ENV RAILS_ENV production
ENV RACK_ENV production

# Install dependencies
RUN apk update && \
    apk upgrade && \
    apk add --update --no-cache \
      build-base \
      imagemagick \
      bash \
      git \
      nodejs \
      tzdata \
      libxml2-dev \
      libxslt-dev \
      postgresql-dev \
    && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/* \
    && bundle config build.nokogiri --use-system-libraries \
    && gem install bundler --no-ri --no-rdoc \
    && mkdir -p /usr/src/i2i

WORKDIR /usr/src/i2i
COPY Gemfile Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock Gemfile.lock
RUN bundle install --jobs 20 --retry 5 --without development test
ADD . /usr/src/i2i

# Precompile Rails assets
RUN bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

Comment: Your Dockerfile?

Comment: Copy the image inside docker and manually perform these commands and see if you could see any errors in commands being executed?

Comment: @TarunLalwani added the dockerfile to the post, thanks.

Comment: Instead of `ruby:2.3.3-alpine` can you try using `ruby:2.3.3-jessie` ?

Comment: It worked! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `ruby:2.3.3-alpine` can you try using `ruby:2.3.3-jessie`.

The problem is that certain commands may require some pre-requisite packages and alpine being a very small image, the packages may be not be present.

So either you can keep using a bigger and more resourceful image like `ruby:2.3.3-jessie` or you can find the dependencies and install them on `ruby:2.3.3-alpine`